# How do I get environment variables for the current user in Windows (SHELL)?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

you probably know, that you can see your windows environment variables in a gui looking like this:

Image: [image: img]
How do only get the variables in the top box?

What I tried:
`echo %path%` in powershell or cmd: it combines the entry for path of both boxes.

How can I prevent that and only see the contents of the top path variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are several ways to get this info... cmd.exe / PowerShell.exe

```
# CMD
For /F "Skip=2Tokens=1-2*" %A In ('Reg Query HKCU\Environment /V PATH 2^>Nul') Do @Echo %A=%C

# Or this...
reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH



# PowerShell
(Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Environment).GetValue('PATH', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')

# Or this
(Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment).PATH

# Or just the path from from what Scepticalist shows
([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User")).Path
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.NET method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable#System_Environment_GetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_) for both User and System (`"Machine"`)

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User")
```